# How do I pass disabled input elements from page 1 to page 2 in Catalyst?

Tags: perl, catalyst

How do I pass disabled input elements (TT) from page 1 to page 2 in [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org) framework?

I can do it with hidden input. Is there any other way to handle it?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with using a hidden form field? What do you want to achieve on a higher level?

Answer (score 0):

From the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12)

> Disabled controls cannot be successful.

If you want to submit a disabled control, then you are probably *doing it wrong*. You probably want to use [readonly](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-readonly) instead.